# CSS selector to match the first empty element

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to apply some styles to the first element of the parent which is empty and a certain type. For example, I have a table something like this

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td></td> <!-- this should be matched -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <td>c</td>
    <td></td> <!-- this should be matched -->
    <td></td> <!-- this should not be matched -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to match only the first `td` in each row which has no content. I've tried this

```css
td:empty:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But that only applies to elements which are both the first of type and empty (e.g. if the cell with 'a' or 'c' was empty), rather than the first empty cell. If I could group selectors like

```css
(td:empty):first-of-type
```

that would produce the correct result in my head as it would look for the first `td:empty` but obviously that's not valid CSS and not how the `:first-of-type` selector works, as that only considers type.

Is it possible to do this using just CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you need a bit more complex combination. First, select all empty, then exclude those that follow any other empty.

```
td:empty:not(td:empty ~ td:empty) {
  ...
}
```

Example

```css
td {
  background: blue;
  width: 20px;
}

td:empty:not(td:empty ~ td:empty) {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td></td> <!-- this should be matched -->
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td> <!-- this should not be matched -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <td>c</td>
    <td></td> <!-- this should be matched -->
    <td></td> <!-- this should not be matched -->
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td> <!-- this should not be matched -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that's only one selector

Comment: Thank you! Clever solution nesting one selector inside another.

Comment: not really, the thing inside `:not()` is a selector

Comment: @JakubKotrs no, the whole thing is *one* selector. Two selectors means that you can write them individually.

Comment: Then you would have about 5 selectors :) td is a selector, empty is a (pseudo) selector, not is a (pseudo) selector, then again td again empty then `~` selector and so on :) . When combining selectors you get a single selector . It's called a `combinator` selector

Comment: Fair point, I'm gonna remove that part about 2 selectors from the answer :)

Comment: @MihaiT - Actually, combinators like `~` are not selectors in any CSS spec. The terminology varies a bit but using Selectors Level 4, the solution is one compound selector, comprising of three simple selectors, `td`, `:empty` and `:not(td:empty ~ td:empty)`. The argument to the third of those is a complex selector of two compound selectors and one combinator. Each of those compound selectors comprises two simple selectors. The total number of simple selectors is 7.